# Can FPGA logic be represented by a matrix/sequence/chain/expression?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, fpga

There is an interesting [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci00057a005) from our chemistry peers, where they achieve to represent molecules into a sequence of characters. This obviously inspired me to think that there must be something similar for sequential circuits.

[image]

Is there any way we can represent an FPGA in a sequence or a matrix? I have gone through IEEE Xplore for a while but no luck.

As I understand from my Digital Systems course, FPGAs are arrays of gates that can be configured to implement a digital logic circuit. Each FPGA is different and has a [different gate capacity](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp059.pdf). I have coded in Verilog before, but **is there any way to export the actual matrix of gates of an FPGA? Or have another type of representation?**

It is mainly for Machine Learning purposes, mainly for a Beta Variational Autoencoder.

Comment: Not sure what's the objective behind representing FPGA architecture as a matrix.

Comment: @MituRaj it is mainly for Machine Learning purposes, mainly for a Beta Variational Autoencoder.

Comment: Okay, you can add this information to the question as well.

Comment: FPGA place and route toolchain should also be considering the whole architecture as an N dimensional matrix: Switch matrices, CLBs, LUTs, Flops.

Comment: One form of FPGA "logic expression/sequence" is known as "HDL program".

Comment: You can express anything as matrix. Sometimes even usefully! So, what should that matrix *do*, what it's used for in your Variational Autoencoder? In itself, I don't see any sensible thing that connects a discrete, non-differentiable device design space with something like VAE, which can't optimize non-differentiable things without a lot of additional tools. So, your problem is woefully underdefined. Yes, you can represent your FPGA, any FPGA as matrix. Choose this 1×1 matrix, it's easiest: \$[0]\$.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the response! Well, basically create a generative model. For example, I want to generate a circuit X for my specific use. You define the type and there is a circuit generated for you. Something similar has been achieved with the discrete molecules I was talking about! VAEs have been used to generate molecules upon defining their target properties. So it is a sequence/chain, which has been used with the VAE, and it spits some wonderful [stuff](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2020/sc/c9sc04026a)

Comment: yes, but the things that solve a specific molecular requirement or that you use GANs for are *differentiable* in the "goodness" of their solutions, in the *loss*. Digital design isn't; replace a single bit in a LUT with something else, and the thing behaves *completely* different. Like anything, VAE aren't magic, you need to understand the problem you're optimizing, mathematically. You might get away with less domain knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller. As you perfectly said, usually the main requirement is the objective to be differentiable. And then you train the neural network using Bayesian optimization techniques or usually a log-likelihood function. But my interest is as you have already spotted, _discrete data_. There is an interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04051.pdf) that produces source code. And as you have mentioned, changing a single character might heavily change the output of the source code. I have previously trained and designed VAEs for handwriting, but want to explore this.

Comment: Just to add more about my final objective. I would like to map different combinational logic or FPGA structures to the regular latent space, to then train the encoder. This obviously comes with an entire mathematical process that I need to develop, but it is all rooted on how can I represent such logic circuits.

Comment: Yep, but source code is in itself much nicer to approximate as extreme value distributed than digital logic! You're literally taking *the* textbook example for "things that aren't what ANNs aren't good at" (that's usually discrete math/satisfiability problems, which automated digital design typically boils down).

Comment: Honestly, your original question "How to represent FPGAs as matrix" is **so** far from the problems you actually need to solve: vote to close as totally out of focus.

Comment: Possibly relevant prior art: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/788489

Answer (score 4):

Not only is this possible, it's actually necessary to load/configure an FPGA. FPGA development tools generate a *bitstream* which is an encoded representation of the configuration, routing and initial values of the primitive elements in an FPGA. Further reading [here](https://www.xilinx.com/html_docs/xilinx2018_1/SDK_Doc/SDK_concepts/concept_fpgabitstream.html) and [here](http://lastweek.io/fpga/bitstream/).

As to the format, the second link above goes into some detail on the Xilinx bitstream format:

> In Xilinx bistream format, each four bytes is a packet (analogous to CPU instruction). Each packet has certain format, it could be a special header packet, or a normal data packet. The header packet follows a simple assembly-like instruction set to dictate the configuration process. The bitstream file is a sequence of these four bytes packets.

It further links to [Xilinx document UG570 (UltraScale Architecture Configuration)](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug570-ultrascale-configuration.pdf) which goes into even more detail on the data format.

Other FPGA vendors can use other bitstream formats (like [Intel's .rbf](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/reference/glossary/def_rbf.htm)) but the concept is always the same: an encoding of the configuration, routing and initial state of the internal elements.

Comment: A much simpler "proof". FPGA is programmed using some HDL. The HDL program is a text file (or files), which is by definition a stream of characters.

Comment: @EugeneSh True, but one HDL "program" can map to many possible FPGA implementations and similarly there are many HDL representations of the same implementation. Bitstream is much closer to (but still not exactly!) a 1:1 correspondence.

Comment: @Eugene Sh - An FPGA does not have to be programmed (designed would be a better word) using an HDL.

Comment: @Type1A - Why do you think a bitstream is not a 1:1 correspondence?  Each bit in the bitstream (ignoring framing, encryption, etc) corresponds to a programmable bit in the underlying SRAM structure (at least in Xilinx world).  Those bits configure the LUTs, interconnects, etc in the FPGA fabric.

Comment: @SteveSh Not true, have you looked into (let's take Xilinx as the example) the .bit format? It's a sequence of commands, not a direct state representation. Variations in the commands (order, etc.) are possible to achieve the same end state.

Comment: If it is one to many, you can always reduce it to 1-to-1 by picking the representation generated by a specific tool.

Comment: @Type1A - Well then, in that case it's not a bitstream, but rather a command file.  The original bitstream data, created with the MakeBits utility, was a 1:1 mapping to the SRAM control bits in the FPGA fabric.

Comment: @EugeneSh., an FPGA is not programmed with an HDL. Programs execute instructions on CPUs and the FPGA isn't one. The HDL implements a logic circuit design. It's a very important distinction.